# Apache ignite In-Memory Database

Tags: ignite

I want to use ignite as a pure in memory db(all data/indexes is in memory) with persistence to disk (similar to Redis), when the service restarts all the data/indexes should be loaded into memory again (automatic warmup).

Update:
There's actually two questions inline here:

1. Can I guarantee that the data is in memory including indexes? (AFAIK persistent-store doesn't guarantee it).
2. Can I warm the cache(including indexes) without writing Java? (implementing CacheStore as described here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading#section-ignitecacheloadcache)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable persistency through xml configuration: https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.6/docs/distributed-persistent-store#section-usage

Comment: @Gilad I would also mention that unlike most IMDBs, Ignite  does not require to pre-load all the data in memory upon restart, so the restarts in Ignite are a lot faster than in IMDBs.

Comment: @Dmitriy there's a way to use Ignite as IMDB which preloads the data using Java, I wish to achieve this using xml configuration since I don't code in Java.

Comment: @alpert first line from your link: "Ignite native persistence is a distributed ACID and SQL-compliant disk store". As mentioned above I want to use in-memory DB.

Comment: @Gilad Ignite can be used as IMDB. Just enable as much persistent space as memory. This way everything in memory will also end up on disk. Nothing else needs to be done.

Comment: @Dmitriy I guess you didn't read my question above, I need all the data and indexes to be in memory from the beginning.

Comment: @Gilad Once you access the data the 1st time, it will be loaded into memory. If you really need all the data to be loaded into memory right away, just iterate through the whole cache on startup and it will be loaded (Ignite cache supports regular iterators). For indexes, usually running a few simple SQL queries will load most of the index into memory as well.

Comment: @Dmitriy Again, I don't want to implement it myself, I want a robust and guaranteed solution: "when the service restarts all the data/indexes should be loaded into memory again".
Also, about the indexes, It's an unproven and unestablished answer, especially when the index is very big.

Comment: @Gilad I think you are asking the wrong question. The question should not be if every last inch of the data got preloaded into memory on startup, but whether the performance is OK or not. What you should do is benchmark the Ignite peformance after you load data (which is memory), then when you restart, which is reloading from disk. My strong intuition is that you will not see much difference, because Ignite starts to aggressively cache data right away.